# Combined pipable operators with RxJS / Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Is is possible (I can't find anything comprehensive on this) to combine multiple pipable operators in one function, so I can pipe it and re-use in a different method as well?

Here is the thing:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.route.url
            .pipe(
                switchMap( (ids: UrlSegment[]) => /* http call */),
                tap(result => /* setting a variable within a service */),
                tap(result => /* some more manipulating and logic */),
                map(result => /* setting a _this_ variable */)
            )
            .subscribe( () => {
                /* some other async tasks, which depend on _this_ variables */
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
            });
      }
```

How do I extract everything within `pipe()` so I can call the same chain of operators from a different method, which would need to perform the same http call and subsequent logic and manipulating?

What I try to achieve is:

```
 this.route.url
   .pipe(
       this.combinedPipableMethod(url: UrlSegment[])
   )
   .subscribe()
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would set a class member value ( `_this_` variable ) in your map. You are supposed to create new data based on a given emission in the `map`. Not perform side effects. Feels like the code in your `map` belongs in your `subscribe` callback.

Comment: You are right. I should change it to `tap` too.

Comment: I think you should just perform these actions in the `subscribe` callback. Don't really see the point of having three `tap`'s. Personally I only use `tap` for logging.

Comment: I don't know really what's the best practice or the initial intention for `tap`was. As I see it - if this is some set and forget, it is more legible within `tap`. I've picked this style on a project I worked on recently and really like it. At `subscribe` I do have further function calls, which deal with `this` context, but there are not present in the other function which reuses this `pipe` so I'd leave it as is.

Comment: While we are at it – can you please look at this question? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746929/using-directive-with-different-services-in-angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract a method:

```
getData(ids: UrlSegment[]) {
   return this.http.get(/* url construction logic */)
      .pipe(
         tap(result => /* setting a variable within a service */),
         tap(result => /* some more manipulating and logic */),
         map(result => /* setting a _this_ variable */)
      );
}
```

And then `switchMap` to it:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.route.url
      .pipe(
          switchMap(this.getData),
       )
       .subscribe( () => {
          /* some other async tasks, which depend on _this_ variables */
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
       });
}
```

Otherwise, you could make a custom operator but it seems like overkill for this purpose:

```
const combinedPipableMethod = () => {
  return source => defer(() => {
    return source.pipe(
       switchMap((ids: UrlSegment[]) => /* http call */),
       tap(result => /* setting a variable within a service */),
       tap(result => /* some more manipulating and logic */),
       map(result => /* setting a _this_ variable */)
    )
  })
}
```

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.route.url
      .pipe(
          combinedPipableMethod(),
       )
       .subscribe( () => {
          /* some other async tasks, which depend on _this_ variables */
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
       });
}
```

Comment: Both variants sound good - how about `this` context? The first one doesn't know any `this` anymore...

Comment: Nevermind. I've changed notation to `switchMap( urls => this.getData(urls)) ` to preserve the context

Answer (score 4):

You can use rxjs `pipe` ( Notice, it's a standalone function, not the method of the Observable) function to combine a sequence of operators into one reusable operator.

```
import { pipe } from "rxjs";
 const customPipable = pipe(
     switchMap( (ids: UrlSegment[]) => /* http call */),
     tap(result => /* setting a variable within a service */),
     tap(result => /* some more manipulating and logic */),
     map(result => /* setting a _this_ variable */)
 )
  this.route.url
  .pipe(customPipable)
  .subscribe()
```

[Here is an article about it](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-combining-operators-397bad0628d0)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the chain within a `Subject`, then simply call `next()` on the subject to force the pipeline to run

```
//Subject for storing pipeline
loadDataSubject = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  loadDataPipe(this.loadDataSubject).subscribe(
     /* some other async tasks, which depend on _this_ variables */
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
  )
}

loadDataPipe(source) {
  return source.pipe(
       switchMap( (ids: UrlSegment[]) => /* http call */),
       tap(result => /* setting a variable within a service */),
       tap(result => /* some more manipulating and logic */),
       map(result => /* setting a _this_ variable */)
  )
}
```

Now feel free to invoke the pipeline run again wherever you feel like with `next()`:

```
 ....
 this.loadDataSubject.next();
 ....
```